# How to search for a particular text using perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

Among the following strings listed below, I only need to search the first string..

```
  test A             <--- only need this string
  test A and test B  <--- don't need this string
  test A and test C  <--- don't need this string
  test A and test D  <--- don't need this string
```

Perl regex I'm using return all four strings above when I only need the first string listed above. How do I filter out the last three strings and only get the first string?

Comment: And why do you want the first string and not the others ? What are the rules ?

Comment: It would be a good idea to put the regex and a sample of test data you are using so far into the question. It is easier to help you when starting from the code you already have.

Comment: Each of those is a separate string? Or are those lines in a file, and you only want to match one of them? Your question is pretty unclear so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html):

```
/^test A$/
```

only matches the *exact* string `"test A"`. But the question remains - why use a regex at all, if you're looking for a specific string?

Comment: thanks for understanding the question to the best of my ability and your resolution works....

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite vague. Assuming that data matches what you've provided, and that your looking to filter a file on a line-by-line basis you can use a `$` anchor as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 

my $infile = 'in.txt';
open my $input, '<', $infile or die "Can't open to $infile: $!";

 while (<$input>){       
     chomp;
     print "$_\n" if /test A$/g;
}
```

Where `$` will match at the end of your string - in this case each line of the input file

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't need the complication of Perl at all, as you can do this readily with grep, as follows:

```
grep "Test A" yourfile | egrep -v "B|C|D""
```